# please tell me where I am wrong

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

An error has been placed I don't think it happened when I was using v4

1. Undeclared identifier 'integer'
2. The 'input' function does not have an argument with the name 'type'
3. Undeclared identifier 'float'
4. The 'input' function does not have an argument with the name 'type'
5. Could not find function or function reference 'stddev'

```
indicator("NASH 2.5 Sigma Bollinger Band", overlay=true)

length = input(title="Length",type=input, defval=20)
mult = input(title="Sigma", type=float, defval=2.5)

upper = ta.sma(close, length) + mult * stddev(close, length)
lower = ta.sma(close, length) - mult * stddev(close, length)

fill(upper, lower, color=gray(0.7))
plot(upper, color=red, linewidth=2, title="Upper Band")
plot(lower, color=red, linewidth=2, title="Lower Band")
```

Answer (score 0):

You've mixed version 5 syntax with version 4 syntax all over the place.

This should work in version 5:

```
//@version=5
indicator("NASH 2.5 Sigma Bollinger Band", overlay=true)

length = input.int(title="Length", defval=20)
mult = input.float(title="Sigma", defval=2.5)

upper = ta.sma(close, length) + mult * ta.stdev(close, length)
lower = ta.sma(close, length) - mult * ta.stdev(close, length)

upperPlot = plot(upper, color=color.red, linewidth=2, title="Upper Band")
lowerPlot = plot(lower, color=color.red, linewidth=2, title="Lower Band")

fill(upperPlot, lowerPlot, color=color.new(color.gray, 0.7))
```